# Rails. How to extend controller class from plugin without any modification in controller file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, ruby-on-rails-plugins, extend

I'm use Rails 2.2.2.
Rails manual said, the way to extend controller from plug-in is:

Plugin:

```
module Plug

def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
  base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  base.helper JumpLinksHelper
end

 module InstanceMethods
   def new_controller_metod
     ...
   end
 end
 module ClassMethods
 end
end
```

app/controller/name_controller.rb

```
class NameController < ApplicationController
  include Plug
  ...
```

end

**Question**: is any way to extend controller from plug-in, **without any modification of controller file**, if we know controller name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you know the name of your controller, do

```
NameController.send(:include, Plug)
```

Comment: Rails initialize plug-ins in first, then controller. So I can run this code only in the end of environment.rb. But same construction: class_eval(%{class NameControler\n include Plung\n end;}) in the end of environment.rb (unexpectedly for me) give no result.

Comment: @neutrino your solve almost perfect, but I can't understand? where i shell run this peace of code? if i shell run it in environment.rb it well be used **only** for first controller execution.

Comment: can't think of anything particular right now. btw, for production this should be enough.